# I get a Page not found error when i try to access my Resume.pdf file on my personal website

Tags: pdf, vite, netlify

I am hosting my website on Netlify and when I try to open my Resume.pdf it gives me a 'Page not Found' error, meanwhile when the website is hosted locally the pdf file opens without any issues, the code in which the href to the pdf is located is in the src/components/Navbar.jsx and that part of the code looks like this:

```
    <li className="w-[160px] h-[60px] flex justify-between items-center ml-[-100px] hover:ml-[-10px] duration-300 bg-[#565f69]">
            <a
              className="flex justify-between items-center w-full text-gray-300"
              href='../Resume.pdf'
              target='_blank'
            >
              Resume <BsFillPersonLinesFill size={30} />
            </a>
          </li>
```

I tried looking at the docs on the Netlify troubleshooting section and i found something about the _recconect file but since it's a document and not a seperate page on my website it shouldn't need to be included, but i tried that too just in case and of course it did not work. I also tried moving the index.html file along with the Resume.pdf into the public folder but later i found that since i created my website with Vite the index.html cannot be placed in any subfolder and must be in the root directory, so that doesn't seem to be the cause of the problem too. The only thing i see that can be the solution for now is to modify that _redirects file, since i see some similar posts regarding similar issues, but regardless i don't know what should go inside that file in this case if not `/Resume.pdf /Resume.pdf 200` , which i have already tried, and the `/* /index.html 200` which i have also tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Resume.pdf` file should be in the `public` folder and the link should be `href="/Resume.pdf"`.

Files in the `public` folder are directly copied without any processing into your site's root directory. Check out: https://vitejs.dev/guide/assets.html#the-public-directory